# Main function in C

Tags: c

I am not sure how will this program behave?
I ran this code but I am not able to figure out any reasoning behind the way it works

```
int main()
{
   return main();
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Have you tried adding log messages to debug what happens instead?

Comment: if you know what *calling a function* is, and what `return` does  , then you have what you need to know to explain this program. If you don't, check a C book

Comment: Badly is the succinct answer.  To return a value, it must call `main()`, which needs to return a value, so it calls `main()`, ... until it crashed.

Comment: You haven't told us *what it does*. I know what I expect it to do, but if you're going to ask about it you should at least describe the behavior you're seeing. (Actually at least two different behaviors are plausible, depending on the compiler.)

Comment: Compiler behavior may vary, but it looks like this code returns the value returned by main which is the value returned by main which is the value returned by main... etc.  An infinite recursive loop, if you will.

Comment: It will recursively call itself to infinity..until it crashes

Comment: thanks to all, It should be an infinite loop.
I got confused with the fact that main function will return int and  here I am trying to return a function.

I realized that program will try to evaluate the function again in return statement before returning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It will help you understand, in part, the hostile reception this question is getting.  We will help people who make an honest attempt at solving a problem, or explaining where they're stuck.

Comment: It is not really an infinite loop; it is an infinite recursion, but that is not quite a loop.  The value returned is the result of the _function call_; that is, the function is called and then the value returned by the called function is returned by `main()`.  It just so happens that the function called is itself `main()`, so everything goes into a tail-spin.  Compare with: `static int abs(int i) { return (i < 0) ? -i : i; } int main() { return abs(-37); }` where `main()` calls a function `abs()` and returns the value that `abs()` returns.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler,this is exactly how i coded and clarified my confusion

Comment: For an explanation, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131703/main-function-in-c

Answer (score 2):

main() is a function by itself. The line return main() calls the function again. So in effect it should run an infinite loop. You wouldn't get any output (you said you ran it. didn't it crash?). 
In reality it would be like staring into a mirror with another mirror placed behind you. You would only see endless reflections. . :)